# The hbm files generated by hibernate ant tools will miss the "DiscriminatorColumn"

Tags: hibernate, annotations, hibernate-tools

I have defined a `Article` entity with hibernate annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WZQ_ARTICLES")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "ARTICLE_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("CURRENT")
public class Article {
    }
```

It uses a `ARTICLE_TYPE` column as the discriminator column. But the generated hbm doesn't contain it.

When I insert a new `Article` entity, it will report an exception said:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "ARTICLE_TYPE" not found; SQL statement:
```